# How to avoid @ManyToOne child entities being fetched on save in Spring Data Jpa?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple `@Entity` with a couple of `@ManyToOne` fields. I fetch the child entities from database and want to simply create a new instance of the parent entity and save that to database.

When I call `myRepository.save(myParentObject)` though, **Hibernate first does a few selects**, one for each field annotated with `@ManyToOne`, and the logs say very clearly `Getting current persistent state for: [...]`. Only once these 2 select operations are completed, the insert finally takes place.

The only solution I found to prevent these undesired `select` operations is declaring the ids of the child entities as `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. I'm using natural ids though, so that doesn't really make sense, and I'd like to avoid that. Implementing `Persistable` on the child instances did not make any difference. How do I avoid the unnecessary selects while not using `@GeneratedValue`s?

```java
@Entity
public class NewspaperArticle {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @NotNull @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="release")
  private ReleaseInfo releaseInfo;

  (...)
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "release_info")
public class ReleaseInfo implements Persistable<LocalDate> {

  // removing @GeneratedValue here causes an additional fetch to happen
  // before a save() on NewspaperArticle happens
  @Id @NotNull @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private LocalDate canonicalDate;
  (...)
}
```

**UPDATE**
A call like this

```java
Optional<ReleaseInfo> maybeRelease = releaseInfoRepository.findById(<date>); 

NewspaperArticle article = new NewspaperArticle();
article.setReleaseInfo(maybeRelease.get()); 

newspaperArticleRepository.save(article);
```

would generate [these logs](https://pastebin.com/fzXieCv3)

Comment: Can you add logs of  select query and code of where child entity fetched ?

Comment: Add unneccesary select query log of applications

Comment: I just added a small update to the question :)